# Macbook Pro Superdrive Only Works With DVD-ROM

Tags: macbook-pro, dvd, optical-drive, dvd-burning

I have a 2007 Macbook Pro with a Superdrive. However, whenever I insert anything other than a DVD-ROM, it waits a moment and then ejects it. It *should* be able to read and write DVD-R, -RW, etc. - below is an excerpt from System Information:

```
MATSHITA DVD-R   UJ-857E:

Firmware Revision:  ZA0E
Interconnect:   ATAPI
Burn Support:   Yes (Apple Shipping Drive)
Cache:  2048 KB
Reads DVD:  Yes
CD-Write:   -R, -RW
DVD-Write:  -R, -R DL, -RW, +R, +R DL, +RW
Write Strategies:   CD-TAO, CD-SAO, DVD-DAO
Media:  To show the available burn speeds, insert a disc and choose File > Refresh Information
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's extremely likely that the drive needs replacing. The lasers get worn out over time and this how they can react.